# Add Ampersand Character Codes to HTML via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add the times sign `&times;` to an HTML template using javascript. Unfortunately the HTML is reading the ampersand character code as a string. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<button id='b'>Add Symbol</button>
<div>&times;</div>
<div id='container'></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('b').onclick = addSymbol;
function addSymbol() {
    var pTag = document.createElement('p');
  var pTagContent = document.createTextNode('&times;');
  pTag.appendChild(pTagContent);

  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.appendChild(pTag);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a2w1w0n3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `createTextNode` javascript does not parse html or entities, you need to use `innerHTML` to have it show the entity.

```
var pTag = document.createElement('p');
pTag.innerHTML = '&times;';
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
var pTagContent = document.createTextNode("\u00d7");
```

Convert that symbol to hex then escape it in js.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is UTF-8 encoded (`<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>`) you can simply write that:

`var pTagContent = document.createTextNode('×');`